# Changing ScotchBox Path to index.php

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have my local dev environment running with ScotchBox, but I have a few questions. I have my entire project directory in ScotchBox's `public` folder, but because my `index.php` file is in a `Website` subdirectory, when I open it in the browser, I have to click into the subdirectory to get to the page.

This isn't a project killer, but it would be nice to change where ScotchBox is looking for `index.php`. Is there a way to do this?